# CodeiIgniter: manually set per-field messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm using CodeIgniter's [form validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) with its per-field rules, but after the validation successfully runs in some circumstances, I want to manually add a per-field error message and re-display the form where the message will be shown with `form_error('field_name')`

I'm not talking about setting custom per-rule error messages:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
```

rather a function that could look like this:

```
form_validation->add_message('field_name', 'my custom message')
```

Comment: Digging into the code I found the way to access directly to the array of messages in this way:   form_validation->_field_data['field_name']['error'] = "My custom message" . Not so elegant..

Comment: where you kept that custom error message.........

Comment: yes, just because PHP lets you easily access all the inner variables, I will ask CodeIgniter crew to add a helper function like above

Comment: You can extend the lib and add your custom method.

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'some message') just redefines the message for the rule named 'required'. In my case validation run was OK but AFTER I want to add a message for a given field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend form_validation, `_field_data` property is protected so you can't access it outside his class or his child class.

`$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'some message')` will not work too, because CI will check this data only when he run the validation and if it associate with a validation rule.

libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add_message($field, $message) {
        //this field was validated without error
        if(isset($this->_field_data[$field]) AND 
         (!isset($this->_field_data[$field]['error']) OR !$this->_field_data[$field]['error']) )

            $this->_field_data[$field]['error'] = $message;
    }
}
```

---

```
$this->form_validation->add_message('field1', 'message for field1');
echo form_error('field1');
```

**Note:**
Messages will not available in `validation_errors()`.
To do so add `$this->_error_array[] = $message`

Comment: Thanks @lighta, in my version of CodeIgniter _field_data array was still public while in current 2.1.3 version has been protected

Comment: You welcome. Notice the version the next time and don't let come CI 3.0 to update your CI app.